# Subtract 2 Dataframes if Numberical Columns; for text use most recent dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes, `df_new` and `df_old` they have same number and names for the fields.  I want to subtract `df_old` from `df_new` if cells are in numerical fields.  If cells are in text fields, I just want to use `df_new` value.

I'm trying to have the result in a separate dataframe called changes.

I need help incorporating a dtype check condition on the formula below so it will work only on numerical fields.

```
  df_new.set_index('Index').subtract(df_old.set_index('Index'), fill_value=0)
```

NEW

```
    Part    Qty     Stock   Notes
0   AAA     40  10  yyy
1   BBB     40  10  yyy
2   CCC     50  20  yyy
3   DDD     40  10  
4   EEE     40  10  
5   FFF     40  10
```

OLD

```
    Part    Qty     Stock   Notes
0   AAA     40  10  xxx
1   BBB     40  10  xxx
2   CCC     40  10  xxx
3   DDD     40  10  
4   EEE     40  10  
5   FFF     40  10
```

CHANGES

```
Part    Qty     Stock   Notes
0   AAA     0   0   yyy
1   BBB     0   0   yyy
2   CCC     10  10  yyy
3   DDD     0   0   
4   EEE     0   0   
5   FFF     0   0
```

Comment: Are you able to show your expected and sample input? 5 rows of each will do.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

to_subtract = [column for column, dtype in new_df.dtypes.items() if is_numeric_dtype(dtype)]
new_df[to_subtract] = new_df[to_subtract] - old_df[to_subtract]
```